# Suggestions to read Keyboard inputs and publish to a topic. (For ex: publish 'w' when the key 'w' is pressed and so on)

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working on a project where I need to send certain data to a programmed embedded system connected through rosserial, which will accordingly execute a function. So, I need to read and publish the keyboard inputs, which will then be subscribed by the embedded system. Please suggest me a solution.
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323954/suggestions-to-read-keyboard-inputs-and-publish-to-a-topic.-(for-ex:-publish-%27w%27-when-the-key-%27w%27-is-pressed-and-so-on)/) by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-24**:
Can you tell us what you've found yourself? We're all here to help, but to avoid suggesting things you've already tried, it would be good to know what didn't work for you.

**Comment by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on 2019-05-25**:
I've tried certain packages like `ros-keyboard` (https://github.com/lrse/ros-keyboard), `keyboard_reader` (https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/keyboard_reader) from Github. `ros-keyboard` requires you to keep the popped up window highlighted for it to work, which is not ideal for my case and the `keyboard_reader` said it couldn't grab my keyboard. I have also tried working with the ROS's own `teleop_twist` to make it fit my requirement but it seemed to not work as it required a very deep knowledge of the python functions to read inputs (like `getch()`, `msvcrt()`, `sys()`, etc). Finally, I tried a funtion called `getchar()` to fail and come here for suggestions.

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-10**:
Does it have to be a keyboard? If you have an xbox controller or other joystick or gamepad, the ros-joy packages have worked great for me.

**Comment by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) on 2019-06-22**:
Yes. It had to be the keyboard to give the inputs. I have it linked in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dug and found some repositories to work on. And here is the keyboard publisher that publishes the ASCII values of the keyboard events.
Repository: https://github.com/Jayadev22/ubiquitousROS.git

---

Originally posted by [Jayadev](https://answers.ros.org/users/38576/jayadev/) with karma: 26 on 2019-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0